# Block URLs on Android Chrome?

Tags: chrome-for-android, url

I'd like to block particular URLs on Android Chrome.

I've tried BlockSite, but the experience is poor - the page still loads for several seconds before the block dialog appears.

Is there any better way to block URLs?

Comment: Apps that use local blocking technology via VPN can totally block certain servers. Usually such apps are designed to block ad-servers but I assume that there is also a possibility to block using a custom server list. One example for such an app is [Blokada](https://blokada.org). Note that such ad-blocking apps are usually not to be found in Google Play Store.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful, I'll give it a go and report back!

Comment: I'm surprised, even shocked that in 2023 I cannot block a URL on my Android device without a third-party tool. What on Earth are the development managers doing? It seems iPhone provides this functionality straight out-of-the-box.